# SAP Business One DI API at item creation should inherit some fields from item group

Tags: sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

In SAP Business One client, imagine you want to add a new item. You set code, name and group. When you set the group SAP proposes to inherit some fields from such item group. You can choose yes or no.

If you do the same thing with DI API, of course there isn't such a proposal. DI API give for granted that you don't want to inherit fields from the item group.

Is there a way to tell DI API to inherit fields from the item group? Or are we obliged to copy them one by one in our program?

Comment: If it copies the defaults through the UI, it's *usually* a good bet that it'll do the same in the DI.
E.g. if you create an order in the DI and add an order line by specifying just the ItemCode, it will populate warehouse, price, account, vat group, etc. automatically (apart from other mandatory fields, maybe).
Unfortunately, it's not always the case, so the best thing to do is just test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this method for maintaining item information from the item group is not exposed to the sdk.

I know that the general ledger information can be maintained using

```
 .GLMethod = SAPbobsCOM.BoGLMethods.glm_ItemClass
```

but for the other 10(ish) fields you will have to manually set them in your code.

```
     .PlanningSystem = BoPlanningSystem.bop_MRP
     .ProcurementMethod = BoProcurementMethod.bom_Make
     .OrderIntervals = "Week"
     .OrderMultiple = 5
     .MinOrderQuantity = 3
     .LeadTime = 20
     .ToleranceDays = 3
     .CostAccountingMethod = BoInventorySystem.bis_Standard
```